# Adding a IF clause to XSL call-template

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm very new to XSL and am trying to edit someone elses code.

The xsl calls a template "formatAustralianDate" and returns a number. However, if @created is null it returns NaN days

```
 <xsl:call-template name="formatAustralianDate">
          <xsl:with-param name="dateValue" select="@Created"/>
 </xsl:call-template> day(s)
```

is there a way I can test if @Created is null (or blank) and if it is, then just return 0 days? or even better, blank

Comment: Please clarify whether the attribute in question is capitalized or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `xsl:choose` here

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="normalize-space(@created)">
      <xsl:call-template name="formatAustralianDate">
         <xsl:with-param name="dateValue" select="@created"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:text> day(s)</xsl:text>
```

If `created` does not exist, or is an empty string (or is a white-space only-string, which normalize-space then converts to an empty string), then the test returns false, and the `xsl:otherwise` is evaluated instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bit rusty on XSLT but perhaps something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:if test="floor(@Created)>0">
 <!-- code here if test passes -->
</xsl:if>
```